# The Structure of Metaphysical Theories

Tags: metaphysics

If I were to state that a metaphysical theory must take the form of a formal axiomatic system would anyone want to disagree? Has anyone argued otherwise?

I haven't seen a counter-view, but then I've hardly seen any discussion of this issue.

Comment: "Questions with no question beyond "am I right" or "what do you think" are off-topic here as this is not a blog".

Comment: As per previous comment, the only "big" attemt to axiomatize metaphysisc was Spinoza's one, but it is difficult to assert that it had success: starting from the very first definitions and axioms, they are highly debatable.

Comment: @Conifold - This is not what I asked. I asked whether anyone would disagree. This includes anyone who has written about the topic. I did not mean just anyone here. I'll make an edit. . .

Comment: I'm not sure why this is on hold but never mind - the lack of objections and the upvotes for Ray's answer indicate the facts of the case.  . .

Answer (score 4):

I think a theory must take the form of a formal axiomatic system.

(1) it has to be axiomatic, since not all propositions can be proved ( one has to start somewhere)

(2) it has to be formal in order the deductions inside the theory to be purely logical.

If one accepts whet precedes, any metaphysical theory, qua theory, has to possess these two features.

Maybe the right question is : *has metaphysics to be a theory, can it even be a theory?*

According to Kant, for example, it cannot: there is no metaphysical theoretical knowledge; the absolute ( God, The World, The Soul) can be thought, but not known.

According to logical positivists, metaphysical questions are not genuine theoretical questions.

Comment: It seems to me your two numbered points are correct. I'm checking this is view is not controversial. Point taken about Kant and the positivists.

Comment: In (1) the "explanation" does not explain the claim, why should there be any axioms at all? (2) is pointless even if it were possible, which it is not. Not even physical theories can be deductive. To be *physical*, they need practical procedures and coordination principles to relate uninterpreted symbology to something empirical. Which model to apply in which situation isn't deductively decided even in classical mechanics, for example. "Axiomatic metaphysics" will be nothing more than a mathematical toy with a big label.

Answer (score 0):

If a metaphysical system is to take the nature of a formal axiomatic system, considering it is metaphysics (ie "being qua being"), it must describe the nature of that axiomatic systems as logic is a part of being.

In these respects you are left with the metaphysical system self referencing itself under it's own rules and it becomes a tautology through its recursive nature.

Under these respects Wittgenstein's work as well as Hegels can be a starting point as they ***imply*** self referentiality in some form or another.  Wittgenstein with the tautological nature of his work, Hegel with the grounding premise of synthesis.

"Being qua being" is a recursive and tautological statement and in these respects metaphysics acts as a means of description that ,in these respects, shares the exact same nature of the sciences.